# What's the best math form of ‘point set' in an article?

Tags: notation, clustering

I am writing a short article on clustering.
Suppose each element of a group of $N$ points is denoted as $\mathbf{x}_i$,
Which of the following is proper to  denote this point set?

1. $\mathbf{X}=\{\mathbf{x}_i, i = 1, \cdots, N\}$ or
2. $X=\{\mathbf{x}_i, i = 1, \cdots, N\}$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is frequent to use bold lowercase for vectors and bold uppercase for matrices. I prefer non bold uppercase for sets.

Comment: In a machine learning context, I would vote to reserve the name $X$ for the matrix whose rows are the row vectors $x_i^T$ (for $i = 1, \ldots, N$). That is a common notation. Perhaps this set could be called $S$ or something.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be $X = \{\mathbf x_1, \ldots, \mathbf x_N\}$.

In many cases in mathematics, symbols don’t have any fixed meaning, so you are free to call things whatever you want. In cases where there are customary symbols, you should use them, to make your work easier to understand. But if you go against the conventions, that doesn’t make your work wrong, it just makes it unusual and hard to read.